# Rails: how to validate that only one record on the many side of a one-to-many relationship is flagged as primary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a one-to-many relationship setup in my Rails app: `Person` has many `Addresses`.  I have added a field to my `Addresses` table called `is_primary`.  How can I enforce, via validations, that only one address has `is_primary` set to true?

Basically I want to say: for all `Addresses` rows that have an `addressable_type` of `Person` and an `addressable_id` of `X`, only one can have `is_primary` set to `true`.  If this is not the case, reject the save and throw up a form validation error.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer something like this, it seems more elegant:

```rb
class Person
  has_many :addresses
  has_one :primary_address, -> { where(primary: true) }, class_name: 'Address'
end

class Address
  belongs_to :person
  validates :primary, uniqueness: { scope: :person_id }, if: :primary
end
```

I think that validation also works as well the other way around?

```rb
  validates :person_id, uniqueness: { scope: :primary }, if: :primary
```

Comment: any idea for forcing `primary: true` whenever no primary exist other than checking it with `where primary: true` and `count`?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to add a new one-to-one association between `Person` and `Address`? That way you'll be sure there can be only one primary address without the need to do any validation and error handling.

```
class Person
  belongs_to :primary_address, class_name: 'Address'
  has_many :addresses
end

class Address
  belongs_to :person

  def is_primary?
    self.person.primary_address == self
  end
end
```

Comment: New Ruby 1.9 syntax! It always confuse long-time Rubyist ;-)

Comment: Gah! Stupid 1.9. I'll delete my comment.