# Rails: How to validate a primary flag on a one to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Decided to update the information here based upon the feedback I have received to date and what I currently have setup.

I have been trying to work out the best way to solve this issue but so far I am not coming up with an answer.  I have two tables: customers and credit_cards.  A customer can have many credit_cards and a credit_card belongs to a customer.  Also, a customer can have many addresses and an addresses belongs to a customer.

In my creditcard table I have a column that indicates if a particular credit card is primary.  The column name is **primary**.  A customer can have many creditcards but only **ONE** can be primary.

I was hoping that this could be done via validations but so far I am coming up empty.  I've done numerous searches but nothing seems to work :(

The following post seems to indicate how this can be done but I couldn't get this to work:
[Validation Solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970466/rails-how-to-validate-that-only-one-record-on-the-many-side-of-a-one-to-many-re)

My customer.rb model file is as follows. It's not the entire code in there but the relevant parts.

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  track_who_does_it :creator_foreign_key => "created_by", :updater_foreign_key => "updated_by"

  has_many :addresses, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a['name'].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true

  has_many :creditcards, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :creditcards, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a['name'].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
  has_one :primary_creditcard, ->{ where(primary: "1") }, class_name: Creditcard, autosave: true

  validates :addresses, presence: true
  validates :creditcards, presence: true
  validates :primary_creditcard, presence: true
end
```

My creditcard.rb model file is as follows.

```
class Creditcard < ActiveRecord::Base
  track_who_does_it :creator_foreign_key => "created_by", :updater_foreign_key => "updated_by"

  belongs_to :customer
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 30}
  validates :card_type,  presence: true
  validates :card_number,  presence: true
  validates :card_exp,  presence: true
  validates :card_code,  presence: true

end
```

When I create a new customer with an address and a credit card I always get an validation error message that states the following:

**Primary creditcard can't be blank**

I would appreciate any help on this.

As per the request, adding in the code from the controller that saves the data:

```
if @customer.update_attributes(customer_params)
  flash[:success] = 'Member was successfully updated.'
else
  flash[:error] = "Member was not updated, please see errors."
end
```

The above is in the update part of the customer controller.

Also, for reference, the customer_params is defined as follows:

```
def customer_params
      params.require(:customer).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :sex, :dob, :cell_phone, :work_phone, :home_phone, :other_phone, :email1, :email2, :referred_via_id,
                                       :referred_cust_id, :cust_notes,
                                       addresses_attributes: [:id, :customer_id, :name, :line1, :line2, :line3, :city, :county, :state, :zip, :billing, :delivery, :addr_notes],
                                       creditcards_attributes: [:id, :customer_id, :name, :card_type, :card_number, :card_exp, :card_code, :primary])
    end
```

Comment: Can anyone help on this issue please?

Answer (score 0):

You could add an additional relation called primary_creditcard and validate it's presence

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :credit_cards
  has_one :primary_creditcard, ->{ where(primary: true) }, class_name: CreditCard

  validates :primary_creditcard, presence: true
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I tried this and it seems to throw an error all the time, regardless if the primary checkbox is checked or unchecked.  I tried changing the where section to "primary: "1" but that didn't seem to make any difference.  Would appreciate any further clarification.  The error message the validation is throwing is "Primary creditcard can't be blank".  Again, this message shows when the primary checkbox is checked or unchecked.

Comment: could you add the action code to the question please

Comment: yea, the action that saves the customer and the credit card, and fails

Comment: does the credit card object get saved? if not what happens if you try creating a credit card object separately, like `CreditCard.create!(customer_params[:creditcard_attributes])`

Comment: I just tried to create a brand new customer rather than update an existing one and same issue.  The customer, address and credit card do not get saved at all.  In regards to trying the Creditcard.create! command, you just want me to run that rather than the if @customer.update_attributes(customer_params) command?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if the reason the customer fails to update  is because the credit card fails to create ( invalid credit card ), so it doesn't get attached to the customer then the customer saving fails

Comment: If I remove the following line from the customer model then everything saves just fine:

validates :primary_creditcard, presence: true

Comment: `customer.primary_creditcard` does it work after saving?

Comment: This is what is being passed at the time of update. You can see that primary is set to "1" but still the error message:  "creditcards_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"David Williams", "card_type"=>"AMEX", "card_number"=>"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "card_exp"=>"12/15", "card_code"=>"XXX", "primary"=>"1", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"14"}}}, "commit"=>"Update Member Account", "id"=>"13"}

Comment: try adding `autosave: true` and see if that helps, `has_one :primary_creditcard, ->{ where(primary: true) }, class_name: CreditCard, autosave: true`

Comment: How do I check that customer.primary_creditcard works?  All my saves are done through the application.  Sorry, not sure how I can test customer.primary_creditcard.

Comment: run a `rails c` session

Comment: Ok, if I removed the validations such that I can save the credit card with primary set, then put the validations back again, start a rails c sessions, do a customer=Customer.find(13) and then customer.primary_creditcard it works fine.  So, why are these validations stopping me from saving a credit card when I check the primary flag?

Comment: I think because the customer object is being saved ( and validated ) before the credit_card object, that's why i suggested adding `autosave: true`, it might help

Comment: There is something weird going on with this.  I was able to enter another credit card against customer id = 13 and it saved. So now customer 13 has 2 credit cards, 1 primary and the other not.  I then checked the primary box for the second card and was able to save that also, meaning I now have two cards both primary!! I unchecked both primary flags and again was able to save.  So then I had two cards and neither was primary.  Once I get to that point I cannot save at all regardless of what combination of checked and unchecked I have on the two cards.

Comment: I did already add autosave: true. Doesn't make any difference.

Comment: I do notice the following in my log, if this helps at all:  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `customers` WHERE (`customers`.`email1` = 'dwilliams@dtw-consulting.com' AND `customers`.`id` != 13) LIMIT 1  (this should not return any rows since customer id=13 has email address dwilliams@dtw-consulting.com.  After this the log shows ROLLBACK.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61450/discussion-between-daveinfl-and-mohammad-abushady).